# Display content on Role base

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I have 5 roles: Admin, Secretary, Teacher, Student and unauthorised user. I would like to display some components like modify button only for Admin and Secretary.

Here are roles I need

```
const auth = useSelector((state) => state.login);
const { isAdmin, isSecretary } = auth;
```

And here is where these are used:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
    { isAdmin || isSecretary &&
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" onChange={handlePhoto}/>
    <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
      <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span" >
        <PhotoCamera />
      </IconButton>
    </label>
    <Button type="submit" color="secondary" variant="contained" size="medium" disabled={photo === 0}> {photo === 0 ? "Selectati poza": "Modifica"}
    </Button>
  </div>
}
</form>
```

Now it works only for isSecretary. I guess its something with my   **isAdmin || isSecretary**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` has a lower precedence than `&&` so you have to use the grouping operator to ensure the intended order of evaluation:

```
(isAdming || isSecretary) && ...
```